# Cloud Functions for Firebase Authentication trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using provider Google and Facebook for authentication using firebase authentication. Now I wanna use Cloud Functions for firebase. I want to push the users information using authentication trigger in functions to database node. Can some one tell me how to use firebase.ref().push() in authentication trigger onCreate(event => ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use firebase-admin

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

return admin.database().ref('...').push(
    {foo: 'someValue'}
);
```